# React - Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: reactjs

Please read the whole scenario before saying its duplicate.

I have a table and on scrolling down the list this error appears in the console.

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

I have read all the posts in the stack overflow and they say to set

```
touch-action : none or passive : false
```

but I am not sure where to set this in my React component page. I don't have any preventDefault or any onClick action defined.

```
<div className="row" style={{ width: '94%', marginTop: '-15px' }}>
    <Table structure={this.structure} dataSet={this.filterableDevicesList} sortBy={this.sortBy} order={this.order} hasSelectionColumn={this.hasSelectionColumn} enableSelectAll={this.enableSelectAll}
  ref={(c) => { this.tableWrapper = c; }} height={500} >
    </Table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `Table`?  The issue is being caused by something inside that component.

Comment: Table is external library - The issue is not caused by that.

Comment: how do you know?  The example you've pasted has no event handlers of any type and so cannot possibly generate that error except as a result of something `Table` is doing.  You should provide a more complete example.

Comment: Without knowing what `Table` is, it's hard to give exact advice. [touch-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) is a css property. Have you tried adding `touch-action: none` for the HTML element rendered for `Table`?

Comment: @bflemi3 I have tried `<div className="row" style={{ width: '94%', marginTop: '-15px' , touchAction: 'none'}}>`but it didnt work

Comment: My best guess is that the HTML element rendered for `Table` component (or a child element) needs to have the `touch-action` property set, not a div wrapping the component. If you open the debugger and add `touch-action: none` to the highest HTML element rendered for `Table` that would be a good start at diagnosing.

Comment: tried that in the debugger and it didnt work

Comment: were you able to fix this? i ran into the same issue. As you mentioned, most of the answers say to set {passive: false}, but if we were dealing directly with DOM api, we could add this object as the second parameter to the addEventListerner call. In React how can we do this?